# Android Studio Expression Evaluation during debugging

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and was trying to get my hands on.

My question is: how can I see the value of any expression which needs to be evaulated?
For instance, in the code below, how can I see the value of `Message.getText()`?

```
    if (Message.getText() == null){
        Message.setError("Invalid Message");flag=true;
    }
```

I have been using Eclipse with PyDev and there I had the option to evaluate any expression while debugging by using the `print` statement.
I was just wondering if there is any equivalent functionality in Android studio

Answer (score 38):

You can just use "evaluate expression" button while debugging.

[image: Evaluate Expression Button]

[image: Evaluating selected part of code]

Answer (score 0):

> the option to evaluate any expression while debugging

Yes. You set a breakpoint and debug, then you can see what the expressions evaluate to

Comment: how can I see what is the expression value? what Messate.getText().toString() would evaluate to ??

Comment: Also for instance I want to check what would Message.getText().toString().isEmpty() would return ? without having to add any extra code. Is there any console where I can see these ??