# How do I find the search query text in a debugger?

Tags: android, searchview

In the [Android debugger window](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/), a [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) has many [fields](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html), some of which are depicted below.

[image]

Which field shows the current query text of the SearchView?

Comment: use searchView.getQuery() in Evaluate Expression

Comment: @ShivamKumar this solved my problem.  It must be done at a certain point in the debugging stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields are not sufficient for displaying the information you need, you can use the [Evaluate Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379887/android-studio-expression-evaluation-during-debugging) as depicted in the first answer to the linked question.

As pointed out by @ShivamKumar, typing in `searchView.getQuery()` at any break point where the stack still has direct access to searchView will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to get specific values from complex elements like views is to use watch.

You can open your watches view (if not opened in debug view) by clicking on the icon with glasses.

You can add single lines of code you can enter to check values or return values of your methods during runtime.

Referencing to Android documentation of [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView)
you should be able to use the getQuery() method to get the value you want.

Add a watch like this: searchView.getItem()