# Android Studio null exception error on a ListView with custom ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, listadapter, custom-lists

[Edited] This is the mainScreen activity xml as requested by some of you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F6F6F6">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Pocket Budget"
        android:textColor="#77dd77"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="January"
        android:textColor="#443c3c"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#77dd77"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#779ecb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#ff6961"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Balance"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="9.5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Expense"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="9.5dp"
        design:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        design:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Income"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="9.5dp"
        design:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
        design:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="₱ 0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="₱ 0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="₱ 0"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Transactions"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view5" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/transacList"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="438dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code for my custom ListView I don't know what's wrong because I'm just a beginner in android development

```
package com.example.admin.test2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenOne.class));
            }
        }, 2500);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.transacList);

        CustomAdaptor cAdaptor = new CustomAdaptor();
        mListView.setAdapter(cAdaptor);

    }

    class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);

            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);
            mTextView.setText("Transportation");
            mTextView2.setText("₱ 100");


            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the code for my custom listview layout that will be implemented in my mainScreen for viewing the image icon with the label and amount

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Amount"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the error that I encountered.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.test2, PID: 9518
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.test2/com.example.admin.test2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.admin.test2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

someone please help solving this problem the application when run is force closing and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: This is the problem: `mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.transacList);` Your mListView is null

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: please show the content of `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: done it's been added

Comment: Have you found a solution to the question?! Then post it or mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is `null`, so you can't set it's adapter. 
Hence you get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

`findViewById(R.id.transacList)` returns null beacuse the **ID** is wrong or the **casting** is wrong or your *custom listview* is messed up. Can't judge that from the code you provided.

Comment: what should I do? what should I input?

Comment: Provide the XML code for activity_main also provide the code for the custom listview. You have provided the code for the custom adapter and not a custom listview in the current post.

Comment: Strang it should work. The id is correct and the call is correct. Could you comment out line 24-29, the timer code. Also set the a breakpoint at line 33. Is the listview still Null? Also try to `evaluate expression`, follow this guide. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4FKs.gif, here is the post to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379887/android-studio-expression-evaluation-during-debugging

Comment: ok, let's break it down. 1. Can you access, findViewById(...), some of the other components in that XML? Like `textView8`? If that also is NULL then you are referencing the wrong XML, you must reference `activity_main`, no other XML. 2. Next step is to comment out all the components and have only `ListView` in that XML, then bring one component back at each time. Until you find who is causing the problem. 3. Are you refrecing the correct **import your_application_package_name.R**?;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ListView "mListView" is not initialized yet, make sure your you are properly initializing it, will be helpful if you share your `activity_main.xml` code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any listviews on your layout, hence you get this exception. Try adding something like this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/transacList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Margins and paddings should be designed for your usage of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the list view, add this line before setting the adapter.
`mListView = findViewById(R.id.*your list view id*);`

Comment: Could be missing from main_activity, we dont know that yet

Comment: No the XML is there