# Moving from one activity to another based on the input in three spinners

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, spinner, timetable

I have three spinners in my activity. So I have to open specific activity based on the input of three spinners; if I have entered "1" in my first spinner "cse" in my second spinner and "b" in my third spinner I have to open the respected activity and so on for different combinations.

I have tried using if statements and the app is crashing every time since.

Please beware of the comments in the code those are the codes which I have tried and didn't get any result.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private Button  btn;
/*TextView selection1;
TextView selection2;
TextView selection3;*/
Spinner spin1;
Spinner spin2;
Spinner spin3;

String[] years = {"1","2","3","4"};
String[] branches = {"CSE","ECE","EEE","CIVIL","IT","MECH"};
String[] sections = {"A","B","C"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    /*List<String> branches = new ArrayList<String>();
    branches.add("CSE");
    branches.add("ECE");
    branches.add("IT");
    branches.add("MECH");
    branches.add("CIVIL");
    branches.add("EEE");*/

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,years);

    //Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //attaching dataAdapter to spinner
    spin1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,branches);
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);

    Spinner spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sections);
    dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);

    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displaycheck();
        }
    });
}
public void displaycheck(){
    /*Spinner s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    Spinner s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    String sp1 = s1.getPrompt().toString();
    String sp2 = s2.getPrompt().toString();
    String sp3 = s3.getPrompt().toString();

    if (sp1.equals("3")&&sp2.equals("CSE")&&sp3.equals("B")){*/
    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent it = new Intent(this,M2.class);
    startActivity(it);
    //}
    /*else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //on selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    /*if (spin1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("3")) {
        if (spin2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CSE")) {
            if (spin3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("B")) {*/
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*Intent it = new Intent(this, M2.class);
                startActivity(it);*/
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

    /*Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.display);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View v){
                                   displaycheck();
                               }
                           }
    );
}

public void displaycheck(){
    Spinner s1 =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    Spinner s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    String ye = y.getText().toString();
    String br = b.getText().toString();
    String se = s.getText().toString();
    if (ye.equals("3")&&br.equals("cse")&&se.equals("b")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ra ra ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent it = new Intent(this, M2.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "po po", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving value to variable which are global - Activity Scope - `spin1, spin2, spin3`.

Instead your are giving value to `onCreate` or Method specific scope; when you're fetching value from it it's never initialized.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private Button  btn;

Spinner spin1;
Spinner spin2;
Spinner spin3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// get spinner in variable
spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
...
// Your adapter, ItemListener, DropDownViewResource

spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
... // Your adapter, ItemListener, DropDownViewResource 

spin3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
... // Your adapter, ItemListener, DropDownViewResource

Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.display);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displaycheck();
    }
 });
}


public void displaycheck(){
 String sp1 = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
 String sp2 = spin2.getSelectedItem().toString();
 String sp3 = spin3.getSelectedItem().toString();

 // Your combinations check
 if (sp1.equals("3")&&sp2.equals("CSE")&&sp3.equals("B")){
 // based on combination - redirect user
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and my app is crashing when i click the `button` .**at com.example.meratimetable.MainActivity.displaycheck(MainActivity.java:59)
        at com.example.meratimetable.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)**         `59:String sp1 = spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();        53:displaycheck();`@VikalpPatel @AhmedR @JohnTinsman

Comment: @RabbaniShaik  - Check what's the value/evaluate of `spin1` and it's related expression as well -  `spin1.getSelectedItem()` in debug mode. If you don't know how to evaluate; do follow the answer from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379887/android-studio-expression-evaluation-during-debugging

Answer (score 1):

To get selected item from spinner you use this

```
String value1 = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String value2 = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
String value3 = s3.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Now you can check the values with any logic for example:

```
if(value1.equals("a") && value2.equals("cse") && value3.equals("b"))
   openActivityCodeHere();
```

Comment: since he has 3 spinners and some activity to check based on the value of those three. If the spinners have unique values from each other he can just concatenate and do a single if.

`String selectedValue = value1 + '-' + value2 + '-' + value3;
if (selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("a-cse-b")) {
    openActivityCodeHere();
}`