# Is there any equivalent for Visual Studio ctrl+alt+Q (debug.quickWatch)?

Tags: android

The command <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in Visual Studio can execute methods in runtime in debug mode.
for example you have this method:

```
int GiveMe2(){
   return 2;
}
```

and in your main program you call it(without putting its return value in a variable):

```
some code...

GiveMe2();

some code...
```

Now in debug mode in visual if I select the "GiveMe2();" line and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, it will open a window and will give me the value 2(executes the method and returns its return value).

Notice that I haven't stored it in a variable, so I cannot find its return value in "Variables" section in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alt + F8 to [evaluate expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382411/10883621) , if I understood your question correctly, this should be the closest to Visual Studios ctrl + alt + Q